# Can an instance from one class change variables in an instance of another class?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have just started with OOP, so these are my very first babysteps!

I am trying to build a simple booking system where a user can book a time slot that has been created by another user via a calendar. I am at a very early stage of the project, so the database hasn’t been set up yet and I’m currently fiddling around with a day class and a time slot class and trying to figure out how to make them interact.

Here’s my code:

```
class dayCL {
    public $dayInMonth;
    public $numBookingSlotsOnDay;

    public function __construct($dayInMonth) {
        $this->dayInMonth = $dayInMonth;
    }
    public function getNumBookingSlotsOnDay(){
        return "Booking slots: " . $this->numBookingSlotsOnDay;
    }
    public function numBookingSlotsOnDay(){
        $this->numBookingSlotsOnDay = $this->numBookingSlotsOnDay + 1 ;
    }
};

class bookingSlotCL {
    public $startTime;

    public function __construct($startTime) {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;
    }
    public function output(){
        return "Start: " . $this->startTime;
    }
};
```

The `numBookingSlotsOnDay` function works as intended when called, but is it possible to integrate a call of it in the `bookingSlotCL`, so it is called on every instantiation of a `bookingSlotCL`?

Example:

```
$day1 = new dayCL(1);
$bookingSlot1 = new bookingSlotCL(1);
$bookingSlot2 = new bookingSlotCL(1);
```

Both booking slots are placed on `$day1` so `$day1->getNumBookingSlotsOnDay` should return “2”.

The calendar is designed so that all days are instantiated as a `dayCL` instance, which means that a `bookingSlotCL` instance would always have a `dayCL` instance to be attached to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add all your `bookingSlotCL` instances to an array in your `dayCL` instance like this:

```
$day1 = new dayCL(1);
$day1->addBooking(new bookingSlotCL());
```

That `addBooking` method could look like this:

```
public function addBooking(dayCL $day) {
    $this->days[] = $day;
    $day->startTime = $this->dayInMonth
}
```

This way your are even able to change your `getNumBookingSlotsOnDay` method to dynamically determine the number of booking slots:

```
public function getNumBookingSlotsOnDay() {
    return count($this->days);
}
```

Comment: echo $day1->days[0]->output(); works too! This is the kind of solution I was looking for! Awesome! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can instantiate the class as a property of the class like so then make calls from it:

```
class bookingSlotCL {

    public $startTime;
    public $dayCL;

    public function __construct($startTime) {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;
        $this->dayCL = new dayCL();
    }

    public function output() {
        return "Start: " . $this->startTime;
    }

};
```

Call it like this:

```
$bookingSlotCL = new bookingSlotCL(1);
$bookingSlotCL->dayCL->numBookingSlotsOnDay(1);
```